# How can I easily change shortcut references to multiple files when a folder name in the path changes?

Tags: windows, shortcuts

I have a NAS drive with a folder structure that needs to have a name of a folder changed, but I have another folder on the same NAS with a bunch of shortcuts that will break when the source folder name changes.

Is there a non-programmer-skilled way of updating all the shortcuts in one folder when the other folder changes name?  I can open the properties of each shortcut and change the name in the target path, but there are hundreds of shortcuts and that would take too long to tack down all the shortcuts to manually change them.

I was hoping something like TotalCommander or another file manager might have a batch process for this kind of fix, but as yet have not found an app for that.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found a little app that does it with a GUI:  http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/ShortcutsSearchAndReplace/